# Unable to glue Cucumber Features to Step definitions

Tags: junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Given the following maven folder structure, for which super-flights-acceptanctests is a child of a parent module, and the following Junit runner class, what is the correct configuration?  Currently any maven goal I try and use to run the tests fails to find the stepdefs and prints the stub code to the console.

[image]

I'm pretty sure I have either the file naming conventions wrong or, more likely, the paths to the glue or features wrong in the @CucumberOptions

Comment: Can you please add the runner class details. Paste the runner class codes.

Answer (score 4):

Try using glue value as `"net.superair.flights.tests"` in `cucumberoptions`

Comment: sorry, the screenshot is wrong, that is in fact what I have, exactly as you've stated

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot you have provided, you are using the definition files **BookStepDefs**,**CostStepDefs**,**SearchStepDefs**.

For using the three definition files you have to specify the path of three definition files in the `glue` option because you have kept the definition files in different path.

So the **glue** option should be,

```
glue={"src/test/java/net/superair/flights/tests/book", "src/test/java/net/superair/flights/tests/cost", "src/test/java/net/superair/flights/tests/search"}
```

Answer (score 0):

glue needs package naming structure - sorted